# Is there a faster way or optimization I can apply to my improvised memory pool?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a couple different objects that allocate certain objects to communicate with each other and I decided to give them each a locally managed memory pool where a node can be tagged as free merely by setting a flag within it.

The idea is like this:

```
struct cat {/**couple data fields*/};

struct rat
{
    rat() : poolIndex_(0), poolSize_(INITIAL_SIZE), pool_(new cat *[poolSize_])
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < poolSize_; ++i)
                pool_[i] = new cat;
        }

    size_t poolIndex_;
    size_t poolSize_;
    cat** pool_;
};
```

I provide a non-member function for `rat` and his friends to resize their pool whenever they run out of free `cat` nodes (giving out the nodes is done via `poolIndex_++ % poolSize_;`). The non-member function is as follows:

```
void quadruplePool(cat*** pool, size_t& poolIndex, size_t& poolSize)
{
    poolIndex = poolSize;
    cat** tmp = new cat *[poolSize*4];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i)
        tmp[i] = (*pool)[i];
    delete[] (*pool);
    (*pool) = tmp;
    poolSize = poolSize*4;
    for (size_t i = poolIndex; i < poolSize; ++i)
        (*pool)[i] = new cat;
}
```

is there something in the code which could give me a speedup from what I have right now? (Speed is by far critical for me)

Comment: Uh, several things. 1) How often is allocation done? 2) If you don't have a general idea of how many times allocation is done per second, profile the code. 3) You might want to try SLAB allocation ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is far more efficient to do an array allocation of `cat`s, and when they are freed, place them in a free list.

```
struct CatPool {
    size_t poolSize_;
    size_t i_;
    cat *pool_;
    cat *free_;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<cat[]> PoolPtr;
    std::list<PoolPtr> cleanup_;

    CatPool (size_t pool_size) : poolSize_(pool_size), free_(0) { grow(); }

    void grow () {
        i_ = 0;
        pool_ = new cat[poolSize_];
        cleanup_.push_back(PoolPtr(pool_));
    }

    cat * get () {
        cat *c = free_;
        if (c) {
            free_ = free_->next_;
            return c;
        }
        for (;;) {
            if (i_ < poolSize_) return &pool_[i_++];
            grow();
        }
    }

    void put (cat *c) {
        c->next_ = free_;
        free_ = c;
    }
};
```

But, you should consider using an existing pool allocator implementation. For example, Boost's `object_pool`.

Comment: I was using a very a similar allocator but my objects represent sort of checkpoints along an execution path that even jumps into a different thread. They allocate some metadata cat node and this keeps getting appended to (to it's next pointer) by others and travels through the producer consumer queue..only at the end is it "freed"...replacing a global cat pool with giving each checkpoint my above (which only grows once or twice before adjusting to the flow) gave me speed gains because they cycle % size and free is as simple as: catnode->isFree = true; I can give this a shot though...

Comment: @PalaceChan: The efficiency of this pool implementation depends largely on whether or not `cat` has things to construct and destruct. If you can lazily initialize each `cat` as it is allocated from the `pool_` array, that would make the `grow` operation cheaper.